# Use Glassfish JMS from remote client

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, glassfish-3

I have glassfish installed on a server with a JMS ConnectionFactory set up jms/MyConnectionFactory with a resource type or javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.

I now want to access this from a client application on my local machine for this I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Properties env = new Properties();
            env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
            env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
            env.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "10.97.3.74");
            env.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
            try {
                connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)
                initialContext.lookup("jms/MyConnectionFactory");
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("JNDI API lookup failed: " + e.toString());
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.exit(1);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
```

When I run my client I get the following output:

```
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
{org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=10.97.3.74, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 org.hibernate.validator.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver detectJPA
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: SJSMQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: REMOTE
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
INFO: MQJMSRA_RA1101: SJSMQ JMSRA Started:REMOTE
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext lookup
SEVERE: enterprise_naming.serialctx_communication_exception
19-Mar-2010 16:09:13 com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext lookup
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:159)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:472)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:437)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at simpleproducerclient.Main.main(Main.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:134)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:1017)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorRuntime.java:375)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:124)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/MyConnectionFactory' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=ithfdv01,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getConnectorConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:804)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:932)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:252)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:171)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:172)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:146)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:176)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:682)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:216)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1841)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1695)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1078)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:221)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:797)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:561)
JNDI API lookup failed: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext targetHost=10.97.3.74,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=ithfdv01,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory]
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2558)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:492)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:528)
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext targetHost=10.97.3.74,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=ithfdv01,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:461)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at simpleproducerclient.Main.main(Main.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:159)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:472)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:437)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: This pool is not bound in JNDI : jms/MyConnectionFactory
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:1017)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorRuntime.java:375)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:124)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/jms/MyConnectionFactory' in SerialContext targetHost=localhost,targetPort=3700,orb'sInitialHost=ithfdv01,orb'sInitialPort=3700 [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getConnectorConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:804)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.obtainManagedConnectionFactory(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:932)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:252)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:171)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:172)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:146)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:176)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:682)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:216)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1841)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1695)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1078)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:221)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:797)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:561)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2558)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:492)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:528)
```

I have looked at a number of posts and have tried a number of things with no success. I can run the following commands on my server:

```
./asadmin list-jndi-entries

UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionNamingProxy$UserTransactionProxy
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl
jms: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext

Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.

./asadmin list-jndi-entries --context jms

MyTopic: org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy
MyConnectionFactory: org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy
MyQueue: org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy

Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools
> ```

This seems to be caused by a [bug](https://glassfish.java.net/issues/long_list.cgi?issuelist=11436) which was fixed pretty recent (15 feb 2010). You need to upgrade to at least [GF v3.0.1 build 05](http://download.java.net/glassfish/v3.0.1/promoted/). Give it a try.

Comment: I have updated to (GlassFish 3 (build 9)) and still see the same error.

Comment: I hadn't update my local version of glassfish only the server version, once I updated my local version it worked with 3.0.1 build 9. Any idea when 3.0.1 will be released?

Comment: It's already released, you're even using build 9. Don't you mean 3.0.2 or so?