# Glassfish V3.x and remote standalone client

Tags: java, glassfish, client, queue, jms

it is absolutely no problem to connect to a **ActiveMQ** as standalone client. The only thing you need is to add the **activemq-all-5.4.1.jar** and there you go...

```
...
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION , "system");
prop.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"manager");
prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
prop.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://localhost:61616");
prop.put("connectionFactoryNames", "TopicCF");
prop.put("topic.topic1", "topic1");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
...
```

Now you want to connect to **Glassfish V3.x** and it seems impossible to get the right libraries and classes in order to connect. While it still was possible in Glassfish V2.x I did not succeed yet to get the equivalent of above code running for Glassfish !

```
...
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.appserv.naming.S1ASCtxFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:3700");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties)
...
```

Does anyone have an answer on this ? No, I dont want to deploy an enterprise app-client just to read from a Glassfish queue. There are similar threads here, but none guides anywhere.

Thanks for any tips

Sven

Comment: another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646302/thinner-standalone-client-for-enterprise-application

Comment: and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478958/use-glassfish-jms-from-remote-client

Comment: did you ever get this sorted , I'm experiencing the same issue ....

Answer (score 3):

This is the complete list of client jars for glassfish 3 :

```
auto-depends.jar
deployment-common.jar
glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar    
internal-api.jar
management-api.jar
bean-validator.jar
dol.jar
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar        
javax.ejb.jar
orb-connector.jar
common-util.jar
ejb-container.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar      
javax.jms.jar
orb-iiop.jar
config-api.jar
ejb.security.jar
glassfish-corba-orb.jar
javax.resource.jar
security.jar
config-types.jar
glassfish-api.jar
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar      
javax.servlet.jar
ssl-impl.jar
config.jar
glassfish-corba-asm.jar
glassfish-naming.jar
javax.transaction.jar
transaction-internal-api.jar
connectors-internal-api.jar     
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar     
gmbal.jar
jta.jar
container-common.jar
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar       
hk2-core.jar
kernel.jar
```

Comment: Excuse me to tell your so, but your reply totally looks like an automated one, here is why I downvoted it.

Comment: Sorry you had to downvote me , its not automated - took me quite a while to figure out the list of jar dependancies - thats why I posted it on a couple of questions - in the hope that it might help someone and save them the frustration that I had to go through.

Answer (score 3):

When connecting to Glassfish V3, there is no need to supply any properties to the InitialContext constructor.  You can simply use the no-arg constructor.  To specify the server name and port, set the `-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost` and `-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort` properties on the JVM, respectively.

As for the libraries, all you should need to include is the gf-client.jar file.  It can be found at $GLASSFISH_HOME/lib.  This jar file will automatically include whatever other libraries are needed.

For more information, please see http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB.  Although that document addresses using EJBs in a stand-alone client, the same solutions apply to using JMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can go see the solution I found when encountering quite the same issue : [With which maven dependencies can i create a standalone JMS client for Glassfish ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675024/with-which-maven-dependencies-can-i-create-a-standalone-jms-client-for-glassfish/5745837#5745837)