# Call glassfish ejb from stand-alone application

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

So I have a simple ejb (@stateless) deployed on a glassfish 3.1 server.

I want to call it from a standalone application.

It's working great if I add the gf-client.jar into my run configuration.

But how can I do if I do not have that file (the server is in another machine) ?

I tried using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>glassfish-naming</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

But I have

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:global
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:252)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:171)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:233)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at be.java.tuto.Application.main(Application.java:17)
```

Thanks.

Comment: added a list of **minimal** dependencies. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I just needed to invoke an EJB deployed on GF from my Tomcat server and resurrected my dependencies. And because I dont want to keep them back for myself :)...
[image: minimal dependencies for gf bean invokation]

My IDE is *Eclipse* so I created an *User Library* containing all the files shown above.

Hope this solves your problem!

---

I was facing the same problem. For just wanting to invoke a GF session-Bean method I had to add the complete *gf-client.jar* to my clients classpath.

My problem was that this library is referencing almost the whole GF-libray-folder and even after a clean-up there were >15 referenced jars left which I had to add to my clients classpath.

For me I did't want this overhead so I decided to call the remote method via JAX-WS webservice.

The advantage of using webservises is that it is very easy to add webservice capability to an already existing session-bean by annotating the bean-class with *@WebService*.

After publishing the bean to the appserver you're able to view your deployed endpoint and getting the WSDL. With this you can generate your webservice-stubs automatically by using the `wsimport`-tool shipped with your JDK and use this generated files in yor client to invoke the remote method.

See example [here](http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/wsimport.html).

Once created those files are portable and can be used in any client.

So if your willing to change the way your client calls the remote method this would be a portable, lightweight (except of a bit more http overhead) and easy to implement alternative.

P.S.
You don't lose the ability of invoking your method via EJB-call.

Hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: The only downside of this is that the semantics of the call are different. With a EJB you can send any serializable Java object, and this is not the case with a web service. For example, the default JAX-WS tools won't all you to send a graph of object (say an object containing another object that has a reference to the parent). This can be worked around, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Sorry to hear! And your right: There is no solution of invoking a GF-Bean without adding the *gf-client*-file (**and** its referencing jars) to your clients classpath :(. Therefore I suggested the WebService approach. Cheers!

Comment: Ok thanks, I understand.  But the problem was not invoking a GF-Bean without adding the gf-client-file but findind a maven dependency for the gf-client-file.  My glassfish server is on a machine and I'm developping on another.  So I don't have the gf-client-file. I tried your solution but it's quite more difficult to understand ...  See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668583/invoke-soap-webservice-returning-list-of-objects-from-java-client-with-axis#comment12280773_9668583)

Comment: Oh, now I understand. For myself I don't work with maven but I took a quick look and found those links for a maven [repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|gf-client) and someone on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675024/with-which-maven-dependencies-can-i-create-a-standalone-jms-client-for-glassfish) facing a similar problem (take a look in his answer, he describes how he solved it for a bean call and gave a link to a minimum dependencies list). Cheers!