# EJB 3.1 remote access

Tags: web-services, rmi, ejb-3.1

EJBs can be accessed with RMI or as SOAP-RESTful endpoint. I want to access a remote EJB from another computer/ip address for example in a standalone application. I can reach to EJBs with web services endpoint then i dont know to reach with RMI. How can i implement this idea. I'm using Glassfish 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [How do I access a Remote EJB component from a stand-alone java client?](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB) document. Code snippets rely on EJB 2 (`Home` interfaces), you should lookup `@Remote` interfaces directly. Of course they must be available on the client side.

## Example

Based on: [Creating EJB3 Sessions Beans using Netbeans 6.1 and Glassfish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish):

### `jndi.properties`:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost = localhost
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort = 3700
```

### `Main.java`:

```
package testclient;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import stateless.TestEJBRemote;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            TestEJBRemote testEJB = (TestEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("stateless.TestEJBRemote");
            System.out.println(testEJB.getMessage());
        } catch (NamingException nex) {
            nex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            fnfex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

## See also

- [Call EJBs Deployed in GlassFish from the NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-call-ejb-on-glassfish)
- [Glassfish V3.x and remote standalone client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311157)

Comment: Can i find a running example? im little complicated.

Comment: @RahmanUsta: I added (hopefully working) example based on [Creating EJB3 Sessions Beans using Netbeans 6.1 and Glassfish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish).

Comment: http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-call-ejb-on-glassfish  This is best article, thanks.