# Getting NullPointerException when running simple JMS

Tags: java, jms

Am trying to run a simple JMS app, sadly got NullPointException . following are the links to the files of the app :

[1. Producer.java](http://ianzepp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaeetutorial5/examples/jms/simple/producer/src/java/Producer.java)

[2. SynchConsumer.java](http://ianzepp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaeetutorial5/examples/jms/simple/synchconsumer/src/java/SynchConsumer.java)

Tools used : Eclipse & GlassFish

following is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at coreservlets.Producer.main(Producer.java:96)
```

Any flash put into this shall be appreciated .

Comment: why did my question get downvoted ?????

Comment: No idea - might be because you linked to the code instead of posting it. Anyway, looks like your DI configuration is not being picked up.

Comment: I answered just because I have 5 minutes, but you get downvoted because your question is very bad asked.

Comment: It sounds guys downvoting my question hold a lot against me or something :D

Comment: Downvotes are not personal, they are directed at the question itself. People have probably downvoted this question because it is unclear and incomplete. You haven't even included your code as part of the question.

Comment: Backed up my question with links to the code . did not want my question to look like an article .

Comment: Try this answer: [SO answer how to setup JMS client in standalone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32568038/912829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your stand-alone application without any container around it, the `@Resource` injections will not work. Instead you have to do manual JNDI lookups for both the connection factory and the queue/topic:

Example:

```
    final Properties initialContextProperties = new Properties();

    final String factory = "jms/ConnectionFactory";
    final String queueName = "jms/Queue";

    //

    final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(initialContextProperties);

    final QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ic
            .lookup(factory);
    final Queue queue = (Queue) ic.lookup(queueName);
```

As for the configuration of the `InitialContext`, look here: [Glassfish V3.x and remote standalone client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683055)

Answer (score 2):

```
connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

connectionFactory, even if static, is never initialized. For this reason it is null and you get the null pointer when you try to access the method inside it.

Two way of fixing.

If the method is static, don't declare the var, just call:

```
ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
```

If the method is not static (strange, for a class that is static), you have to do something like:

```
private ConnctionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
```